# Use SQL to return table rows that match multiple search criteria

Tags: asp.net, mysql, .net, sql

I'm trying to perform some simple table filtering using SQL, ASP.NET and query string parameters.
I've set up my project so that there is a form with a 'search' text field and a 'price' text field, and upon submitting the form the query string parameters are updated, like so:

```
mydomain.com?search=test&price=100
```

The SQL statement should return the rows that meet the search criteria but if one is blank, the other should still bring back data. Currently, when both 'search' and 'price' are valid, the correct rows are returned but if one of them is empty, nothing is returned.

Here is my code snippet:

```
var search = Request["search"].IsEmpty() ? "" : Request["search"];
var price = Request["price"].IsEmpty() ? "" : Request["price"];

string sql = "SELECT * FROM Items WHERE ('%" + search + "%' is null OR item_name LIKE '%" + search + "%') AND ('%" + price + "%' is null OR item_price < " + price + ")";
```

It is my understanding that if the 'value is null' statement is true, then that entire 'AND' statement within ()'s is set to null are therefore ignored. If it is false then the 'OR..' statement is ran.

Why isn't the SQL statement working the way it should?

Comment: Initially DO NOT use string concatenation. Be aware of sql injection.

Comment: xexeexexexeex. I mean exactly what @ RussellUhl means !!! So be very careful with that.

Comment: It is better to write more lines that to risk a disaster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides your being exposed to SQL injection, here is what your query looks like when `Request["search"].IsEmpty()` :

```
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE '%%' is null (...) ;
```

The string `'%%'` is not null (it is a two-characters string).

Instead you want to so something like this:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Items WHERE '" + search + "' = '' (...)" ;
```

So that `sql` becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE '' = '' (...)
```

Alternatively you could drop the test `'' = ''` altogether, because `'%%'` is in fact `LIKE` any string:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Items WHERE '%" + search + "%' LIKE item_name";
```

If `Request["search"].IsEmpty()` then your query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE '%%' LIKE item_name (...) -- always true
```

The above is only meant for educational purpose, because it produces sub-optimal queries. The right approach would be to build the query dynamically:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Items WHERE";
if (!Request["search"].IsEmpty()) {
    sql += "item_name LIKE '%" + search + "%' AND";
} // else no condition on "item_name"
if (!Request["price"].IsEmpty()) {
    sql += "price < " + price ;
} // and so on
```

This is only a proof of concept though. Some more tweakings will be required.

Comment: '%%' is ANY string.  the '%' character is a wildcard.  It is true, however, that '%%' will never be null

Comment: Thanks YaK, that solves what I was trying to do but it looks like I won't be using this method in production anymore!

Answer (score 4):

I found an interesting little solution to this.  It's kinda hackish, but it works:

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 == 1";
var search = "blahdiblah";
if search is not "" {
    sql += " AND item LIKE '%"+search+"%'";
}
```

Just adapt it to your code.

So initially you say "give me everything", and then based on whether or not you have values, you start whittling away at the requested data with ANDs and ORs.

FOR THE LOVE OF GOD PLEASE GET RID OF YOUR INLINE SQL!!!  I was not kidding in the comments.  If my syntax is correct, if someone enters `');DROP TABLE Items;--` in your search text box, it WILL drop your ENTIRE TABLE.  That line will close the quote, end the statement, drop the table, and comment the rest out.  the resulting line would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE ('%');DROP TABLE Items;--%' is null OR item_name LIKE '%" + search + "%') AND ('%" + price + "%' is null OR item_price < " + price + ")
```

Which is, in fact, a dropped table.  The first statement will probably error out, and then the second will execute, and the rest is commented out and will not be executed.

Comment: Haha, thanks Russell. I had no idea of the potential security threats, so I will look to do it some other way

Comment: The `WHERE 1 == 1` trick is in fact a very widely used "hack" because it allows appending the conditions without having to make a special case for the first condition. This has no impact on performance because the optimiser (cleverly :) detects that as a tautology and ignores it.

Comment: @mmmoustache: In general, stored procedures are a pretty decent way to go.  That way, the data gets passed in as a parameter.  Even if you have the same inner sql, it gets treated as "val1 == val2?" rather than affecting the actual statement itself.  Take a look at the mysql documentation for sprocs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html.  Also, in general, a procedure is used to do a bunch of things and maybe return a table, whereas a function is used to do a bunch of things and then get back a single result  (like a boolean or an int or something... not a whole table).

Comment: well that worked out nicely. exactly the character limit.  Anyway: @YaK:I was unaware that was widely used, that's good to know, thanks!  And those clever optimizers are quite nice.